# Understanding arguments to a signed distance field function

Tags: glsl, signed-distance-field

I'm looking into drawing a box using [Inigo Quilez's code](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm):

```
float sdBox( in vec2 p, in vec2 b )
{
    vec2 d = abs(p)-b;
    return length(max(d,vec2(0))) + min(max(d.x,d.y),0.0);
}
```

Do I understand correctly that for `p` is a point anywhere in 2d space?

If so, what is `b`?

I tried to draw a 2x2 rectangle at origin (assuming `b` is then `vec2(2,2)`) and do those calculations but nothing good came out. It should calculate the distance between the point and nearest edge, right?

Comment: "nothing good came out" - what output did you expect, and what output did you get instead?

Comment: Well, it calculated 0, when the distance as drawn on paper was 2. I think I dont understand whats `b` is clearly.

Comment: What arguments did you provide to get this outcome? (If you explained this in your question, I wouldn't have to ask follow-up questions)

Comment: b = vec2(2,2), p = 1,2

Comment: The point 1, 2 is exactly on the edge of a box centered at the origin with half-extents (2, 2), so 0 is exactly the number we'd hope to get, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is the size of the box, measured from the center to one corner - what we often call the "half-extents" of the shape.

So a box 10 units wide and 2 units tall would use `b = vec2(5, 1)`

To draw a 2x2 square, you'd want `b = vec2(1, 1)`